# QtCore.signal not doing anything

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am a beginner with PyQt5 and I am having trouble to use QtCore.signal

I'd like to send a signal when I press my buttons and switch the current widget displayed.
I don't have any errors when I run my code but when I press the buttons nothing happen and I guess it is because I am doing something wrong with the QtCore.Signal

Here is my code :

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from ui_Page_accueil import Ui_MainWindow
from ui_NouvelleVerif import Ui_Dialog as Ui_NouvelleVerif
from ui_NouvelleVerifEssieux import Ui_Dialog as Ui_NouvelleVerifEssieux
import sys


class MainWindowUi(Ui_MainWindow):

    to_NouvelleVerif = QtCore.Signal()

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        #self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.pushbutton_handler1)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.pushbutton_handler2)
        


    #def pushbutton_handler1(self):
    #    self.to_MainWindow.emit()

    def pushbutton_handler2(self):
        self.to_NouvelleVerif.emit()
        
 
    
class NouvelleVerifUi(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_NouvelleVerif):

    to_MainWindow = QtCore.Signal()
    to_NouvelleVerifEssieux = QtCore.Signal()

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.pushbutton_handler1)
        #self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.pushbutton_handler2)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.pushbutton_handler3)


    def pushbutton_handler1(self):
        self.to_MainWindow.emit()

    #def pushbutton_handler2(self):
    #    self.switch_window.emit()

    def pushbutton_handler3(self):
        self.to_NouvelleVerifEssieux.emit()
        


class NouvelleVerifEssieuxUi(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_NouvelleVerifEssieux):

    to_NouvelleVerif = QtCore.Signal()

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.pushbutton_handler1)


    def pushbutton_handler1(self):
        self.to_NouvelleVerif.emit()


class Controller :
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
    MainWindow = MainWindowUi()
    NouvelleVerif = NouvelleVerifUi() 
    NouvelleVerifEssieux = NouvelleVerifEssieuxUi()     


    
        
    

    def __init__(self):
        
        self.widget.addWidget(self.MainWindow)   # create an instance of the first page class and add it to stackedwidget
        self.widget.addWidget(self.NouvelleVerif)   # adding second page   
        self.widget.addWidget(self.NouvelleVerifEssieux)
        self.widget.setCurrentWidget(self.MainWindow)   # setting the page that you want to load when application starts up. you can also use setCurrentIndex(int)

        


    def show_MainWindow(self):
        self.NouvelleVerif = NouvelleVerifUi()
        
        self.NouvelleVerif.to_MainWindow.connect(self.show_MainWindow)
        
        self.widget.setCurrentWidget(self.MainWindow)

    def show_NouvelleVerif(self):
        self.MainWindow = MainWindowUi()
        self.NouvelleVerifEssieux = NouvelleVerifEssieuxUi()
        
        self.MainWindow.to_NouvelleVerif.connect(self.show_NouvelleVerif)
        self.NouvelleVerifEssieux.to_NouvelleVerif.connect(self.show_NouvelleVerif)

        self.widget.setCurrentWidget(self.NouvelleVerif)
        
    def show_NouvelleVerifEssieux(self):
        self.NouvelleVerif = NouvelleVerifUi()

        self.NouvelleVerif.to_NouvelleVerifEssieux.connect(self.show_NouvelleVerifEssieux)

        self.widget.setCurrentWidget(self.NouvelleVerifEssieux)
    
            

def main():
     
    controller = Controller()
    controller.widget.show()
    sys.exit(controller.app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Nothing calls those `show_` functions. The only reference to them is *inside* them. You should move almost everything you do in those functions into the `__init__`, except for the `setCurrentWidget()` calls.

Comment: @PaleniLuca Please provide a minimal working example

Answer (score 0):

@musicamante I don't know why I though the `QtCore.Signal` could be call even if he was in a function which has not been called. I did what you said and I realise I made another mistake with the widgets.

In the controller class they are create and add to the `QStackedWidget` in the `__init__`, but I was creating new ones and trying to set them as `CurrentWidget` without adding them to the `QStackedWidget`.

@alexpdev I wanted to navigate through my three differents with `pushButton` UI this way :

Start with `MainWindowUI`

```
MainWindowUI pushButton_2.clicked --> set the current widget display to NouvelleVerifUI

NouvelleVerifUI pushButton_1.clicked --> set the current widget display back to MainWindowUI 

NouvelleVerifUI pushButton_3.clicked --> set the current widget display to NouvelleVerifEssieuxUI  

NouvelleVerifEssieuxUI pushButton_1.clicked --> set the current widget display back to NouvelleVerifUI
```

Now everything work I did what you said @musicamante and I also use the UI created at first.

```
class Controller :
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
    MainWindow = MainWindowUi()
    NouvelleVerif = NouvelleVerifUi() 
    NouvelleVerifEssieux = NouvelleVerifEssieuxUi()        
 
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.widget.addWidget(self.MainWindow)   # create an instance of the first page class and add it to stackedwidget
        self.widget.addWidget(self.NouvelleVerif)   # adding second page   
        self.widget.addWidget(self.NouvelleVerifEssieux)
        self.widget.setCurrentWidget(self.MainWindow)   # setting the page that you want to load when application starts up. you can also use setCurrentIndex(int)
        
        
        self.NouvelleVerif.to_MainWindow.connect(self.show_MainWindow)
        self.MainWindow.to_NouvelleVerif.connect(self.show_NouvelleVerif)
        self.NouvelleVerifEssieux.to_NouvelleVerif.connect(self.show_NouvelleVerif)
        self.NouvelleVerif.to_NouvelleVerifEssieux.connect(self.show_NouvelleVerifEssieux)

    def show_MainWindow(self):
        self.widget.setCurrentWidget(self.MainWindow)

    def show_NouvelleVerif(self):
        self.widget.setCurrentWidget(self.NouvelleVerif)
        
    def show_NouvelleVerifEssieux(self):
        self.widget.setCurrentWidget(self.NouvelleVerifEssieux)
```

Thank you all for your time